# Convert Nested Dataframe to a simple Dataframeframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Really need help, as tutorials don't seem to address this issue. I spent a whole day on this and can't find a solution.

I downloaded API data and converted from json to python dictionary format. However, the dictionary is very complex, it has a dictionary of dictionaries.

Here is the head of the dict:

```
df[1]
Out[47]: 
flight_date                                             2020-07-07
flight_status                                            scheduled
departure        {'airport': 'Findel', 'timezone': 'Europe/Luxe...
arrival          {'airport': 'Francisco Sá Carneiro', 'timezone...
airline          {'name': 'TAP Air Portugal', 'iata': 'TP', 'ic...
flight           {'number': '6794', 'iata': 'TP6794', 'icao': '...
aircraft                                                      None
live                                                          None
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

[Picture of the dict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgLiq.png)

Within the rows Departure and Arrival there are iata çodes (for example: 'iata':'LUX') for different airports. See example below.

**Departure dictinary:**

```
{'airport': 'Findel', 'timezone': 'Europe/Luxembourg', 'iata': 'LUX', 'icao': 'ELLX', 'terminal': None, 'gate': None, 'delay': None, 'scheduled': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'estimated': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'actual': None, 'estimated_runway': None, 'actual_runway': None}
```

I am trying to simplify these complex dictionaries into a simple table composed of columns of departure iata codes and corresponding arrival iata codes for a given date.

If you have any ideas about how to solve it or know good documentation, please send it across.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could create minimal dataframe which we could use in code.

Comment: for single item in dictionary you can do `df['departure_iata'] = df['departure'].apply(lambda item: item['iata'])`. Similar for `arrival_iata`

Comment: or try `df['departure_iata'] = df['departure'].str['iata']`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, it gives a KeyError: 'departure'

Comment: I have added a picture of the dict - maybe that will help to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single value in dictionary you can use

```
df['departure_iata'] = df['departure'].apply(lambda item: item['iata'])
```

For few values you can use similar with `Series`

```
df[['departure_airport', 'departure_iata']] = df['departure'].apply(lambda item: pd.Series([item['airport'], item['iata']]))
```

For all values you can use `... = df['departure'].apply(pd.Series)` but it needs to write all column's names manually

```
df[['departure_airport', 'departure_timezone', 'departure_iata', 'departure_icao', 'departure_terminal', 'departure_gate', 'departure_delay', 'departure_scheduled', 'departure_estimated', 'departure_actual', 'departure_estimated_runway', 'departure_actual_runway'] ] = df['departure'].apply(pd.Series)
```

---

Using `assign` you can make it simpler but it doesn't add prefix `departure_` to new columns - and it can make problem if you want to do the same with `arrival` which has the same names.

```
df = df.assign(**df['departure'].apply(pd.Series))
```

but you can set prefix in `Series`

```
df = df.assign(
    **df['departure'].apply(
        lambda item: pd.Series({'departure_'+key:val for key,val in item.items()})
    )
)
```

---

**EDIT:** Little simpler with `add_prefix()`

```
df = df.assign(**df['departure'].apply(lambda item:pd.Series(item).add_prefix('departure_')))
```

or

```
df = df.assign(**df['departure'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('departure_'))
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1,2,3],
    'B': [4,5,6],
    'departure': [
        {'airport': 'Findel', 'timezone': 'Europe/Luxembourg', 'iata': 'LUX', 'icao': 'ELLX', 'terminal': None, 'gate': None, 'delay': None, 'scheduled': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'estimated': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'actual': None, 'estimated_runway': None, 'actual_runway': None},
        {'airport': 'Findel', 'timezone': 'Europe/Luxembourg', 'iata': 'LUX', 'icao': 'ELLX', 'terminal': None, 'gate': None, 'delay': None, 'scheduled': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'estimated': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'actual': None, 'estimated_runway': None, 'actual_runway': None},
        {'airport': 'Findel', 'timezone': 'Europe/Luxembourg', 'iata': 'LUX', 'icao': 'ELLX', 'terminal': None, 'gate': None, 'delay': None, 'scheduled': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'estimated': '2020-07-07T06:30:00+00:00', 'actual': None, 'estimated_runway': None, 'actual_runway': None},
    ]
} # columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df['departure_iata'] = df['departure'].apply(lambda item: item['iata'])
#df['departure_iata'] = df['departure'].str['iata']
print(df['departure_iata'])

df[['departure_airport', 'departure_iata']] = df['departure'].apply(lambda item: pd.Series([item['airport'], item['iata']]))
print(df[['departure_airport', 'departure_iata']])

df[['departure_airport', 'departure_timezone', 'departure_iata', 'departure_icao', 'departure_terminal', 'departure_gate', 'departure_delay', 'departure_scheduled', 'departure_estimated', 'departure_actual', 'departure_estimated_runway', 'departure_actual_runway'] ] = df['departure'].apply(pd.Series)
print(df[['departure_airport', 'departure_iata', 'departure_timezone']])

#----

df = df.assign(**df['departure'].apply(pd.Series))
print(df)

df = df.assign(
    **df['departure'].apply(
        lambda item: pd.Series({'departure_'+key:val for key,val in item.items()})
    )
)
print(df)

df = df.assign(**df['departure'].apply(lambda item:pd.Series(item).add_prefix('departure_')))
print(df)

df = df.assign(**df['departure'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('departure_'))
print(df)
```

---

**BTW:** Instead of `assign()` you can also use `concat()`

```
df = pd.concat([df, df['departure'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('departure_')], axis=1)
print(df.columns)
```

You can even drop column `'departure'`

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['departure'], axis=1), df['departure'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('departure_')], axis=1)
print(df.columns)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Convert rows to columns

```
df = df.T
```

In example I had to use `apply(eval)` beacuse I have dictionary as strings and have to convert to Python dictionary.

```
text = '''flight_date                                             2020-07-07
flight_status                                            scheduled
departure        {'airport': 'Findel', 'timezone': 'Europe/Luxe...'}
arrival          {'airport': 'Francisco Sá Carneiro', 'timezone':'...'}
airline          {'name': 'TAP Air Portugal', 'iata': 'TP', 'icao':'...'}
flight           {'number': '6794', 'iata': 'TP6794', 'icao': '...'}
aircraft                                                      None
live                                                          None'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', header=None)

df.rename(columns={0:'index'}, inplace=True)
df.index = df['index']
df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
print(df)
print('---')

df = df.T
print(df)
print('---')

df['departure'] = df['departure'].apply(eval)

df['departure_airport'] = df['departure'].apply(lambda item: item['airport'])

print(df['departure_airport'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, it gives a KeyError: 'departure'

Comment: I have added a picture of the dict - maybe that will help to understand

Comment: Now I see - I expected you have column `departure` and row `0` or `2020-07-07` because it seems more natural in pandas - but you have column `0` and row `departure`. Probably you would have to use `df[1]['departure']` to get it but problem will be add it as next rows beacuse `pandas` was contructed to work with columns and easily add new column.

Comment: you can use `df = df.T` to transpose table - convert rows to columns. You may also need `df = df.drop(0, axis=0)` to remove first row with names `flight_date`, `flight_status`, etc

Comment: thanks a lot, transposing worked, after which your initial code.